# jquery autocomplete in variable length list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Trying to figure out how to do this, using **Sanderson begincollectionitems** method, and would like to use autocomplete with a field in each row.

I think I see how to add a row with an autocomplete, just not sure the approach for existing rows rendered with `guid`.

Each row has an of field that the user can optionally point to a record in another table.  Each autocomplete would need to work on the html element `idfield_guid`.

I'm imagining using jquery to enumerate the elements and add the autocomplete to each one with the target being the unique of field for that row. Another thought is a regex that maybe let you enumerate the fields and add autocomplete for each in a loop where the unique field id is handled automatically.

Does that sound reasonable or can you suggest the right way?  Also is there a reasonable limit to how many autocomplete on a page?  Thanks for any suggestions!

Edit, here's what I have after the help. data-jsonurl is apparently not being picked up by jquery as it is doing the html request to the url of the main page.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON($(this).data("jsonurl"), request, function (return_data) {
                    response(return_data.itemList);
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        };

        $('.ac').autocomplete(options);
    });

    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(
    x => x.AssetId, 
    new { 
        @class = "ac",
        data_jsonurl = Url.Action("AssetSerialSearch", "WoTran", new { q = Model.AssetId }) 
    }) 
%>
```

And the emitted html look okay to me:

```
    <input class="ac" data-jsonurl="/WoTran/AssetSerialSearch?q=2657" id="WoTransViewModel_f32dedbb-c75d-4029-a49b-253845df8541__AssetId" name="WoTransViewModel[f32dedbb-c75d-4029-a49b-253845df8541].AssetId" type="text" value="2657" />
```

The controller is not a factor yet, in firebug I get a request like this:

```
http://localhost:58182/WoReceipt/Details/undefined?term=266&_=1312892089948
```

What seems to be happening is that the $(this) is not returning the html element but instead the jquery autocomplete widget object.  If I drill into the properties in firebug under the 'element' I eventually do see the data-jsonurl but it is not a property of $(this). Here is console.log($this):  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plugin. Simply apply some know class to all fields that require an autocomplete functionality as well as an additional HTML5 `data-url` attribute to indicate the foreign key:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(
    x => x.Name, 
    new { 
        @class = "ac", 
        data_url = Url.Action("autocomplete", new { fk = Model.FK }) 
    }) 
%>
```

and then attach the plugin:

```
var options = {
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON($(this).data('url'), request, function(return_data) {
            response(return_data.suggestions);
        });
    },
    minLength: 2
});

$('.ac').autocomplete(options);
```

and finally we could have a controller action taking two arguments (`term` and `fk`) which will return a JSON array of suggestions for the given term and foreign key.

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term, string fk)
{
    // TODO: based on the search term and the foreign key generate an array of suggestions
    var suggestions = new[]
    {
         new { label = "suggestion 1", value = "suggestion 1" },
         new { label = "suggestion 2", value = "suggestion 2" },
         new { label = "suggestion 3", value = "suggestion 3" },
    };
    return Json(suggestions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You should also attach the autocomplete plugin for newly added rows.

Comment: Thanks!! I did not know about data-, that is very clever! $(this).data("jsonurl") is not returning the correct url for some reason. I'm getting the page address instead with undefined (http://localhost:58182/WoReceipt/Details/undefined?term=266&_=1312892089948).  I'll post code when I can but don't understand it. If I hard code the url it works...